# Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: file, casting, nsstring

I want to read a file, line by line and then assign to each line a variable.

I have the following code:
    NSString *aFilePath= [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"db.def"];
    NSArray *lines = [aFilePath componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

```
char *server = [[lines objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String];
```

Here I get the following error:
Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

As far as I can see: lines objectAtIndex:0 returns id. I tried to cast it to NSString
with no difference
    char *server = [[(NSString *) lines objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String];

I simply want to read a line and make it a char *.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The qualifier you’re missing is const. -`UTF8String` returns a `const char *`, so server should also be declared `const char *`.